# How to analyze user journey like appsee of flutter app?

Tags: flutter, appsee

i want to analyze or record user journey, like https://www.appsee.com/ does.
then i found this [Analysing user journey in Flutter apps using Appsee](https://medium.com/@vipinkagrahari/analysing-user-journey-in-flutter-apps-using-appsee-4e60f15ad762)

But its just black like other people response on the comment session.
how to achive like that, or any plugin or tutorial ?
thanks

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?